# git - revert Modifications - get data back

Tags: git, netbeans

I am using NetBeans as my IDE.

I had a new file in my branch. Accidently I used the function "Revert Modifications" on this new file. Now it's gone. Is it possible to get this file and its content back? (this file never got commited)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if it was never committed, it is gone. Maybe you can recover it from netbeans, if there is sth like local history as in intellij or eclipse...

Comment: Thank you very much. I was only searching for a solution via git. If in NetBeans I rightclick the folder, which contained the deleted file, I had the function History -> Restore Deleted. There I could restore the deleted file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to perform action "Undo" but it all what you may try...